# No getting IP when connecting through switch

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, switch

I am trying to acquire IP from a router through switch.
Network structure:

[image]

However, no getting IP when my pc is connected through a switch. 
Things I've tried:

1. Connect my pc to router when DHCP enabled [Worked]
2. Connect my pc to router when DHCP disabled and static ip is set on my pc [Worked]
3. Connect my pc to switch when DHCP enabled [Didn't work]
4. Connect my pc to switch when DHCP disabled and static ip is set on my pc. [Didn't work]

Is there anything wrong with my setting?

Comment: If your running Windows 10 an update was released yesterday that fixes a dhcp bug.  Download KB3206632 to fix this problem.  Telling you to update windows isn't an acceptable answer if it's submitted by me, so you can self-answer, I suggest if the update does work then you self-answer

Comment: How did you check that it does not work in case 4? You can't `ping` the router in that case? What is the error?

Comment: @SuB I can't connect to the Internet for case 3 and 4.

Comment: @Ramhound Cool, thanks. I will give it a try later.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the router through the switch? Are you sure you wired them up correctly?

Comment: Hi @Seth, No, I can't connect to the router. I connected the LAN port on the router to the switch. I assume the port number on the switch shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: With that specific model it shouldn't matter. On other switches you'd need to connect using a crossover cable and/or a special uplink port. Does your machine show you a connection after you plug it into the switch? Do the lights for the connection on the router do their blinking business? Do they do that for the connection PC <-> Switch and Router <-> Switch?

Comment: Hi @Seth, Yes, both lights are blinking. (the one connects to router and the one connects to my machine). When I type in command, ipconfig /renew. Error occurs like below. "An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet 4 : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out."

Comment: @Mike - You really should install that patch.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, Yea, I've tried but still no luck.

Comment: Do you have any vlan tagged on the switch ? Can you ping your DHCP server if you set a static Ip ? Make sure the previous Ip is leased otherwise you'll have to manually delete the A record from DNS server plus make sure you have a reverse DNS zone in your DNS server and last make sure that the firewall is off and you're flushing your DNS by running an elevated command prompt and typing ipconfig /flushdns then ipconfig /registerdns

Comment: Issue is just resolved now. It seems there are two devices connected to switch has been playing around. The connectivity to the Internet is restored as soon as I unplug those two devices. Thanks everyone's help. Much appreciated.